# How to make code of converting Docx to PDF in this code?

Tags: python, python-docx

```
import aspose.slides as slides    
import time
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import os
import aspose.words as aw

root = Tk()
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent = root, title = "Choose files")
files = root.tk.splitlist(files)
start = time.time()
for f in files:
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if ext == ".ppt":
        pres = slides.Presentation(f)
        pres.save(f+".pdf", slides.export.SaveFormat.PDF)
    elif ext == ".docx":
        doc = aw.Document(f)     #problem part
        doc.save(f+".pdf")
end = time.time()
print("Time Taken:%f secs" %(end-start))
```

This is the code of converting ppt and docx to PDF.
I am trying to make the system to check whether the extension of selected files from file dialog are pptx or docx and do correct process.
But when I tried to make code of docx part, converting docx to pdf didn't work.
I tried multiple times with different libraries.(docx2pdf, aspose)
Could someone help me out with this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on what `didn't work`? You could for example give us the list of the libraries you tried, the error messages they sent you back each time? more precision about  what `doesn't work` `==`  easier it to help you 

Comment: @itMaxence Thanks for your comment. When I tried to run the code I uploaded, it didn't show any errors but converting docx to pdf itself didn't work which is the problem part. Libraries I tried are aspose.words, docx2pdf. I would like to use these libraries if the code is working and other libraries are good to use if converting code is worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason your program is not work is **its not getting into the if, elif, else statement.**

`ext = os.path.splitext(f)` returns a list for example `[C:\\hello\\filename",".docx"] but you are comparing whole list i.e` if ext==".doc"`, which obviously returns false.

Here's what you can do:

- change `if ext==".docx"` to `if ".docx" in ext`. or,
- change `if ext==".docx"` to `if ext[1] == ".docx"`.

Comment: @BellaLee , Glad could help you :)